# Thread safe pass-through operator

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, new-operator

I'm overriding `new()` and `new[]()` operators for our *heap memory manager*. `new()` has a *mutex* and is thread-safe, but I have not added a mutex to `new[]()`, which works as a *pass-through operator*, since I suspect it will be on the stack when called. Is it correct that `new[]()` will be on the stack and will not need a mutex of its own?

```
/*!
\brief Override the Standard C++ new [] operator
\param size [in] Number of bytes to allocate
\exception std::bad_alloc
\returns Pointer to the start of the allcoated memory block of \c size bytes
\todo Check if this is thread-safe or if it needs a mutex lock, return address probably is on the stack so it should be ok
*/
void *operator new[] (size_t size)
{
    return operator new(size);
}

/*!
\brief Overrides the Standard C++ new operator
\param size [in] Number of bytes to allocate
\exception std::bad_alloc
\returns Pointer to the start of the allcoated memory block of \c size bytes
*/
void *operator new(size_t size) 
{
    MM_ENTER_CRITICAL_SECTION(CMemoryManager::mutex)
    // Memory manager code removed since it's outside of the question context
    MM_LEAVE_CRITICAL_SECTION(CMemoryManager::mutex)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct that new will be on the stack and will not need a mutex of its own?

Operator `new[]()` works just like `new()` but instead of allocating a single object, it allocates an array of objects.  I don't know what that has to do with the stack, the objects allocated are allocated on the heap and a pointer to that memory is returned to you.

The only thing that's on the stack is the pointer itself, but that is the case with both versions of `new`.

Seeing that `new[]()` calls `new()` then **I don't see a reason** why you'd need a mutex in `new[]()` because `new()` is already protected by a mutex.  Any thread that calls `new[]()` will have to wait if another is already inside `new()`.

Comment: I think that is true only if `return operator new(size);` is on the stack when entering `new[]()`, but if it's treated as a local variable then I think it must have its own mutex - but I'm not sure.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen I'm sorry I can't make sense of what you're saying? Please elaborate?

Comment: Oh, it was a reference to the last paragraph in your answer. I know the difference between `new()` and `new[]()` so no worries there, we override both since, at least on Windows, there are some OS assert debug code inside `new[]()` when debug compiling which we don't want to call - but that's outside the scope of the question so I won't go into that.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I'm not asking about how new() allocates memory, I'm asking if I need a *mutex* inside `new[]()` in my code above - I already know that `new()` and `new[]()` both allocate memory on the heap. I'm sorry that I can't explain the problem better than this.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen I highlighted the part of my answer that states the answer. You don't need another mutex.

Comment: And the reason for your answer is that `return operator new(size)` is already on the stack when entering `new[]()` and not placed inside a local memory variable, or?

Comment: I don't know what the stack has to do with this. The reason is that `new[]()` calls `new()` which has a mutex protecting it. That is the only reason.  It has nothing to do with stack anywhere.  It's the order of function calls that's important

Comment: Afaik, when a method is called its address pointer is first placed on the stack, if the address pointer is first stored in a local variable it is considered not thread-safe since the local variable has a shared mutable state. It all comes down to how the compiler interprets the C++ code, so even if my code does not have a local variable a compiler may, in some cases, add one during compilation.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Stack variables are inherently threadsafe: the stack is threadlocal

Comment: Stack variables are inherently threadsafe if access to them is never signaled off that stack.

Comment: @MartinJames I know, but what I wanted to know is will the `new[]()` in my code only be asigned to the stack like it is coded now?